# Custom styles to be assigned for caption's styleref

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I've generated my own styles in Microsoft Word, and it brought up a lot of headache regarding the generation of figure's and table's captions that includes chapter number. I went through a lot of similar question on the internet, but none of them addresses my issue. I currently have the following error on all the captions:

```
Error! No text of specified style in document.
```

And using built-in microsoft word styles is not an option, since they can't be assigned to multi-tier level lists... I've tried the followings field code:

```
{ STYLEREF "HEADER 1" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

And it didn't solve my problem. Any idea on how to assign custom styles to styleref for captions ?

Comment: If the "HEADER 1" style is used only in headers or footers then STYLEREF cannot find instances of it in the document itself. Just to verify this is the case, type some text somewhere within the document and apply this style to it. Now refresh the field and see if it picks up that text.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, but it's not only in header or footers, and I've tried that, it doesn't work...